# Rewrite Rule in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I conisder moving to Nginx but I want you to ask if is possible to rewrite urls into that schema, and if you could help me a bit:

- A url like http://example.com/username into profile.php?u=username. But then, will I have problems in accessing other pages like e.g. home.php
- A url like http://example.php/questions/102039/that-question into questions.php?quid=102039

  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to [rewrite URLs with Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).

- Your first example can be handled easily by wrapping the rewrite with a block which checks if a file (home.php in your example) exists; if it doesn't, then it tries the redirect into the `profile.php` request. (See the [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files) syntax for this.)
- Your second example is just as simple:

  Rewrite ^/questions/(\d+) /questions.php?quid=$1

(Because the matching expression is not anchored at the end, it should accept any string after the digits, but I haven't checked that so I'd recommend you test it.)